# Сортировка List<String> по числам

Tags: java, сортировка, list

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот есть список в

```
List<String> list
```

из таких элементов: n1007, n1001, n6751, n4420, n3347, n9044, n2046.

Как отсортировать элементы этого списка в порядке возрастания по числам, чтобы получилось: n1001, n1007, n2046, n3347, n4420, n6751, n9044?

Answer (score 5):

Я бы предложил своим компаратором воспользоваться. Варианта 2: или оставаться на стрингах

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("n1000", "n110");

Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // если строки разной длины, то более короткое
        // точно меньше, что можно получить сравнением длин
        if (o1.length() != o2.length())
            return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        else
            //если длины равны - сравниваем просто как строки
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Или парсить в инты/лонги

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("n1000", "n110");

Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        //откусываем в o1.substring(1) букву n, парсим число в Long  и сравниваем лонги
        return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(o1.substring(1)), Long.parseLong(o2.substring(1)));
    }
};
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Что будет быстрее сложно сказать, но я ставлю на первый вариант

Answer (score 2):

```
list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(1))))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки коллекций можно использовать метод [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). В качестве компаратора в данном случае подойдет [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):

```java
List<String> list =
        Arrays.asList("n1007", "n1001", "n6751",
                "n4420", "n3347", "n9044", "n2046");

Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

System.out.println(list); // [n1001, n1007, n2046, n3347, n4420, n6751, n9044]
```

---

В `8` версии `Java` появился метод [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
list.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```